# Error message handling due to exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, try-catch

i have a code to restart a service in an event which does other functions too.

I have a try catch in the event for everything within the event like this:

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {               
            applyChangesAndCheckRestartService();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading page.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private void applyChangesAndCheckRestartService()
    {
        string svrPortNo = CommonCodeClass.getTagValue(CommonCodeClass.xml_SvrPortNoTag, CommonCodeClass.configLocation + CommonCodeClass.configXML);               

        if (!ApplyChangesForSettings())
        {                
            return;
        }

        if (svrPortNo != tbSvrPortNo.Text)
        {               
            CommonCodeClass.CheckToRestartService();
        }
    }
```

Now if there is an error during ApplyChangesForSettings() i will get an error popup "Error loading page".

If there is an error in CheckToRestartService() i will get the same error because of the try catch.

Is there a better way to handle this.

Like i dont mind the error loading page for ApplyChangesForSettings() but for CheckToRestartService() i would like to see an error like "unable to restart service".

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks

```
internal static void CheckToRestartService()
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(CommonCodeClass.resartServiceMessage, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            CommonCodeClass.RestartService(CommonCodeClass.serviceName, 60000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they throw different exceptions?  If they do you could use exception filtering:

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {               
        applyChangesAndCheckRestartService();
    }

    // catch service start exceptions
    catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
    {
        // display message that couldn't start service
    }

    // catch rest
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading page.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** this is assuming you're calling something like `ServiceController.Start()` which throws `InvalidOperationException` on failure, you could easily throw this yourself on your own error condition or create your own custom exception.

```
if (/* service didn't start */)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not start service.");
}
```

Comment: I like your idea, but how to the ioex and catch it. i have edited my answer to show the restart service function. please have a look. thanks

Comment: @user175084 sorry, i think i lost something in your comment.  Is that how to *throw* the ioex?

Comment: yup sorry.. like how to create a separate exception for it??

Comment: @user175084 Sorry, I was assuming you were just catching the exception that ServiceController itself throws when Start() fails, but you could easily throw it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to handle this situation is throwing an exception when someone of your internal methods fails and catch the message in the btnApply_Click.

```
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error",  .....);
```

The rightest way is to create your own exception type and inside the methods, if there is a fail condition throw your own exception. For example create a class like this

```
public class RestartServiceException : Exception
{
    public RestartServiceException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
    // You could also write other constructors with different parameters and use internal logic
    // to process your error message
}
```

and then, use an instance of that class when the fail condition arise inside your CheckToRestartService method

```
   if(fail == true)
       throw new RestartServiceException("The service could not be started because .....");
```

Comment: I would like to do it this way. is there a sample or an example page which has steps for the above??

Comment: It is not really complicated. You need to create a class derived from the base class Exception. Then you could implement your methods or internal vars to represent your message and error conditions. At this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx) you could find the reference materials from MSDN

Answer (score 1):

You either need to

- catch the exception in `applyChangesAndCheckRestartService`
- or you could pass an `enum` by [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) f.e. called `RestartStatus`

  ```
  enum RestartStatus{success, unableToRestart, unableToApplySettings};

  RestartStatus status = RestartStatus.success;
  applyChangesAndCheckRestartService(status);
  if(status != RestartStatus.success) //....

  private void applyChangesAndCheckRestartService(out RestartStatus status)
  {
      // set the status variable accordingly
  }
  ```

A third way is to use [custom exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx) that you can catch separately.

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe you just need to wrap the different functions with separate try/catch blocks:

```
    try {
        if (!ApplyChangesForSettings())
           return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading page.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    if (svrPortNo != tbSvrPortNo.Text) {      
        try {         
            CommonCodeClass.CheckToRestartService();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to restart services.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Or, you could consider catching different types of exceptions, if they threw different types:

```
string errmsg = string.empty;
try { 
    DoSomething();
}
catch (FooException) {
   errmsg = "There was a Foo error";
}
catch (WidgetException) {
   errmsg = "There was a problem with a Widget";
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   errmsg = "General problem: " + ex.Message;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errmsg))
   MessageBox.Show(errmsg);
```

See also:

- [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx)